# Функция не возвращает никакого значения

Tags: c++, функции, вывод

Есть два массива. Есть перегруженная функция которая должна считать среднее арифметическое для элементов этих массивов. Должен работать return. Он есть, но не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double func(double * mas, int kol);
float func(float * mas, int kol);

void main() {
 setlocale(0, "");
 const int kol = 5;
 double mas[kol];
 float mas1[kol];

 for(int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
  cout << " Введите " << i + 1 << " елемент double массива > ";
  cin >> mas[i];
  cout << " Введите " << i + 1 << " елемент float массива > ";
  cin >> mas1[i];
 }
 func(mas, kol);
 func(mas1, kol);
 system("pause");
}

double func(double * mas, int kol) {
 double sum = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
  sum += mas[i];
 }
 printf("Среднее арифметическое double массива > \n");
 return sum/kol;
}

float func(float * mas1, int kol) {
 float sum = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
  sum += mas1[i];
 }
 printf("Среднее арифметическое float массива > \n");
 return sum/kol;
}
```

Comment: А куда оно должно его возвращать? Вы же игнорируете возвращаемое значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("Среднее арифметическое float массива > %f\n",sum/kol);
```

и

```
printf("Среднее арифметическое double массива > %lf\n", sum/kol);
```

`return` - это возвращать вызывающей функции, а не на экран...